# Initiate appium driver for android using ruby capybara

Tags: ruby, appium, capybara

How can I initiate appium driver for android using ruby capybara framework

```
def register_cloud_mobile_driver
  Capybara.register_driver :cloud_mobile do |app|
    opts = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(
      securityToken: @sec_token,
      platformVersion: 'xx',
      platformBuild: 'xxxxx',
      manufacturer: 'xxx',
     model: 'Galaxy S22',
      resolution: '1080x2340',
      deviceStatus: 'CONNECTED',
      location: 'xxxx',
      appPackage: 'xxxxx',
      appActivity: 'xxxxx.activity.SplashActivityV2',
      takesScreenshot: false,
      screenshotOnError: true
    )
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :remote, url: $server_url, desired_capabilities: opts)
    Capybara.default_driver = cloud_mobile
  end
end
```

Result:

```
"undefined method `testExecutionTags' for nil:NilClass
"WARN: Screenshot could not be saved. `page.current_path` raised exception: 
#<ArgumentError: rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given>.
```

Comment: You are going to need to provide a bit more context here

Comment: Try to use the appium_capybara gem. It's enabling appium support in capybara
https://github.com/appium/appium_capybara